# Showing entirely a div just partly visible in an overflow auto container

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with fixed dimensions and `overflow:auto` applied on it and two sub divs in it:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="content-1"></div>
  <div class="content-2">
      aaaaa<br>
      aaaaa<br>
      aaaaa<br>
      aaaaa<br>
      aaaaa<br>
      aaaaa<br>
      aaaaa<br>
      aaaaa<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.outer{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content-1{
  height:250px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content-2{
  height:250px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

[As you can see here](https://codepen.io/n1p/pen/RqVeXB), the second div is partly hidden by scroll. I'd like to show that second div entirely regardless of the scroll position. Tried with z-index, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Edit: trying to have this:

[image]

Comment: So what's the first div supposed to do?

Comment: @Paulie_D are you referring to content-1 div? It is there just to illustrate the actual layout for my case.

Comment: Then I'm struggling to understand what effect you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to do but could you just add margins ?

Comment: @BojanKolano  i've updated the question with what exactly am I trying to achieve

Comment: So you want your div to be fixed ?

Comment: You cannot do that with css alone - as soon as you change the overflow to scroll, you cannot show any overflow as it will be hidden by the scroll.  Also what's the point of having it scrollable if you just want to show it?   All you would be doing is opening yourself up to having stuff hidden behind the lower section

Comment: Basically, you can't (as it stands). You're trying to have **two** overflow conditions and that can't happen. Plus I'm not sure of the value of that effect but that's another issue.

Comment: In my specific case the outer div with overflow is a modal and the div partially visible is an ul type dropdown that opens clicking a button. I want that dropdown  to be shown somehow without scrolling.